# web chart with hover events

Tags: python, graph, hover, charts

I am after a library with a Python interface to render nice looking charts with hover events for each point.

[ChartDirector](http://www.advsofteng.com/gallery.html) does what I want, but I would prefer an open source solution.
[OpenFlashChart](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart-2/) looks good, although ideally I would want a non-Flash solution.

Any other contenders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not strictly Python, but you may want to look at [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/). (assuming by web chart you mean those that are to be embedded on web pages)

Comment: hmm looks interesting. Damn IE!

Comment: amazing - looks like I will try Flot then!